# Stability of Tikhonov Regularization

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, regularization

I'm learning about Tikhonov regularization

$$\underset{x\in X}{\arg\inf}\left\{||Ax-b||^2+\lambda ||x||^2\right\}$$

I have read that the solution keeps the residual $||Ax-b||^2$ small and is stabilized through the $\lambda ||x||^2$ term. Can anyone help me understand why that is? I can see that the term prevents overfitting, but I can't quite see how it helps stabilizing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L_2$ norm, the solution for $x$ is
\begin{align*}
x = (A^T A + \lambda I)^{-1}A^T b
\end{align*}
The instability in this solution lies in the inverse. If $A$ have columns which are nearly linearly dependent, then $A^TA$ is "nearly non-invertible". In other words, the condition number will be very large. The $\lambda I$ helps stabilize this inverse, and will always lower the condition number.

Comment: Yes, it is the $L^{2}$ norm that is used. That makes sense! I completely forgot that the solution was relying on $(A^{T}A+\lambda I)^{-1}$. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 4):

In order to understand Thikonov's stabilization, it helps to first look at the ordinary least square solution $x^*$:

\begin{align*}
x^* = (A^T A)^{-1}A^T b
\end{align*}

We see that it's necessary to calculate the inverse of $A^T A$ and this might not be possible, if $A$ has nearly linearly dependent columns. But let's take a closer look onto this, by factorizing just the suspicious term by a singular value decomposition.

Then $A^T A = U \Sigma V^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are the eigenvectors and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix that contains the non-zero eigenvalues. It's not of special interest here that $U=V$, but it is very important that the pseudoinverse $(A^T A)^{-1}$ is found by inverting $\Sigma$.

More specific, the reciprocal of each eigenvalue, let's say $\sigma_i$ has to be found. And this might get difficult, if two columns are nearly linear dependent. In this case, $\sigma_i$ is very small and the result of the division gets very large and tiny pertubations of $\sigma_i$ lead to large fluctuations of the inverse.
It is possible to monitor such cases and as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3100284/646082) answer already mentions the condition number is one of these indicators.

The solution that Thikonov provides to overcome the problem is simple, but very effective: just take a positive variable $\lambda$ and add it to the denominator. This will bound the overall result and stabilize the solution:

\begin{equation}
\Sigma_{ii}^+ = 1 / (\sigma_i + \lambda)
\end{equation}

As we now have identified the cause of instabilities and inserted a term that prevents them, we can add the same to our known equation and role it back:
\begin{equation}
U (\Sigma + \lambda I) V^T = U \Sigma V^T + \lambda U V^T = A^TA + \lambda I 
\end{equation}

And finally, we arrive at the well known:

\begin{align*}
x^* = (A^T A + \lambda I)^{-1}A^T b
\end{align*}